# algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmic

I want to write something like

```
\Repeat {comment}
    \State 
\until
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE Initialize 
    \REPEAT (for each episode)
    \UNTIL $s_t$ is terminal
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{spacing}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

But I can not put the comment on the same line of the repeat command.
Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, I edited my first post!

Answer (score 2):

In the package documentation of the package algorithm that can be found [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), it is written on page 9

> Because the mechanisms used to build the various algorithmic structures make it
>   difficult to use the above mechanism for placing comments at the end of the first
>   line of a construct, the commands \IF, \ELSIF, \ELSE, \WHILE, \FOR, \FORALL,
>   \REPEAT and \LOOP all take an optional argument which will be treated as a
>   comment to be placed at the end of the line on which they appear.

As usual you have to use brackets for optional argument. Thus using `\REPEAT[for each episode]`, should give the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I want. I will have a look at the documentation...